# Why does group_by() in dplyr not work when switching from sum to counting unique occurrences?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, grouping

The below MWE code works fine for summing data frame values, whereby the user selects which type of period to group by in the radio buttons in the "Sum the data table columns:" section rendered at the bottom. This grouping is performed in the `summed_data()` object below in the `server` section.

However I'm also trying to count the number of occurrences where Period_2 == 1. When I comment out the currently uncommented `summed_data()` section below, and uncomment the currently commented-out `summed_data()` for performing unique row counts, and try running the code, it fails. But if I run this unique row count function in the R console, as shown immediately below, it works fine and gives the desired results (manually changing the "Period..." in the `group_by(...)` section)!

```
   data <- data.frame(
      ID = c(115,115,111,88,120,16),
      Period_1 = c("2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03"),
      Period_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4),
      ColA = c(1000.01, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
      ColB = c(15.06, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65)
    )
    
    filter(data, Period_2 == "1") %>%
    group_by(Period_1) %>%
    summarise(count = length(unique(ID)))

 Period_1 count
  <chr>    <int>
1 2020-01      2
2 2020-02      1
```

So, to me the problems appears to lie in the dplyr code below `group_by(!!sym(input$grouping))`. Does anyone have a suggestion for solving this?

MWE code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

ui <-
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 8,
          h3("Data table:"),
          tableOutput("data"),
          h3("Sum the data table columns:"),
          radioButtons(
            inputId = "grouping",
            label = NULL,
            choiceNames = c("By period 1", "By period 2"),
            choiceValues = c("Period_1", "Period_2"),
            selected = "Period_1",
            inline = TRUE
          ),
          DT::dataTableOutput("sums")
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      ID = c(115,115,111,88,120,16),
      Period_1 = c("2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03"),
      Period_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4),
      ColA = c(1000.01, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
      ColB = c(15.06, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65)
    )
  })
  
  colNames <- reactive({c(input$grouping, "Col A", "Col B") })
  
  # summed_data <- reactive({
  #   filter(data(), Period_2 == "1") %>%
  #     group_by(!!sym(input$grouping)) %>%
  #     summarise(count = length(unique(ID)))
  # })
  
  summed_data <- reactive({
    data() %>%
      group_by(!!sym(input$grouping)) %>%
      select("ColA","ColB") %>%
      summarise(across(everything(), sum))
  })
  
  output$data <- renderTable(data())

  output$sums <- renderDT({
    summed_data() %>% 
      datatable(
        rownames = FALSE,
        colnames=colNames() # < add colNames()
        )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem were the `colNames()` that you defined and added to your call to `datatable`. I commented those lines out and it works. The problem didn't arise with your `sum` `data.frame` because here the `colnames` were actually present in the `data.frame`, which is not the case in the `length(unique))` `data.frame`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

ui <-
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 8,
             h3("Data table:"),
             tableOutput("data"),
             h3("Sum the data table columns:"),
             
             radioButtons(
               inputId = "grouping",
               label = NULL,
               choiceNames = c("By period 1", "By period 2"),
               choiceValues = c("Period_1", "Period_2"),
               selected = "Period_1",
               inline = TRUE
             ),
             DT::dataTableOutput("sums")
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mydat <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      ID = c(115,115,111,88,120,16),
      Period_1 = c("2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03"),
      Period_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4),
      ColA = c(1000.01, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
      ColB = c(15.06, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65)
    )
  })
  
  # colNames <- reactive({c(input$grouping, "Col A", "Col B") })
  
  summed_data <- reactive({
    print(input$grouping)
    mydat() %>%
      dplyr::filter(Period_2 == 1) %>%
      dplyr::group_by(!!sym(input$grouping)) %>% 
      dplyr::summarise(count = length(unique(ID)))
  })
  
  # summed_data <- reactive({
  #   print(input$grouping)
  #   data() %>%
  #     group_by(across(all_of(input$grouping))) %>%
  #     select("ColA","ColB") %>%
  #     summarise(across(everything(), sum))
  # })
  
  output$data <- renderTable(mydat())
  
  output$sums <- renderDT({
    summed_data() %>% 
      datatable(
        rownames = FALSE,
        # colnames=colNames() # < add colNames()
      )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```